# How to initialise a variadic template that relies on previous entries?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement a Neural Network. To do so, I thought I could use template parameters for most of the hyper-parameters. It's started to get difficult, and I suspect it may not be possible to achieve what I want.

I have a base Neuron class

```
class NeuronBase { /* virtual output method */ };
```

and from that I have an input Neuron

```
class InputNeuron : public NeuronBase { /* overrides output */ };
```

as well as proper neuron type that's used in most layers

```
template<std::size_t NumInputs>
class Neuron : public NeuronBase
{
public:

    Neuron(std::array<NeuronBase*,NumInputs> prevLayer)
    :
        m_inputLayer(prevLayer)
    {}

    /* override output method */

protected:
    std::array<NeuronBase*,NumInputs> m_inputLayer;
};
```

These are contained in a layer:

```
template<std::size_t NumNeurons>
class Layer
{
public:
    typedef std::array<NeuronBase*,NumNeurons> NeuronArray;

    Layer(NeuronArray neurons)
    :
        m_neurons(neurons)
    {}

    NeuronArray& GetNeurons() const { return m_neurons; }

protected:
    NeuronArray m_neurons;
};
```

and these layers are encapsulated by a network:

```
template<std::size_t NumInputs, std::size_t NumOutputs, std::size_t... HiddenSizes>
class NeuralNetwork
{
public:
    NeuralNetwork()
    :
        m_hiddenLayers(/* WTF do I do?? */)
    {
    }

protected:
    std::array<InputNeuron,NumInputs> m_inputLayer;
    Layer<NumOutputs> m_outputLayer;
    std::tuple<Layer<HiddenSizes>...> m_hiddenLayers;
};
```

which would be created like this:

```
int main()
{
    NeuralNetwork<126,7,252,63> nn;

    return 0;
}
```

which results in a Network with 126 inputs, 7 outputs, and two hidden layers, the first hidden layer 252 and the second with 63 neurons.

I've ommited a bunch of stuff that you would usually see in a Neural Network.

The problem I have is initialising the layers in the network. The `m_hiddenLayers` needs to be initialised with the first element referencing the input layer and the rest using the previous item in the `std::tuple`, and they also need to be created with the correct type, i.e. `Neuron` instead of `NeuronBase`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm now wishing for a <kbd>...</kbd> key... This should do what you're looking for:

```
template<std::size_t NumInputs, std::size_t NumOutputs, std::size_t... HiddenSizes>
class NeuralNetwork
{
public:
    NeuralNetwork()
    : m_hiddenLayers{makeHiddenLayers()}
    , m_outputLayer{makeOutputLayer()}
    {
    }

private:

    // Creates an array of pointers to each neuron of the input layer
    template <std::size_t LayerSize, std::size_t... LayerIdx>
    auto makeLayerPtrs(
        std::array<InputNeuron, LayerSize> &inputLayer,
        std::index_sequence<LayerIdx...>
    ) {
        return std::array<NeuronBase *, LayerSize>{&inputLayer[LayerIdx]...};
    }

    // Creates an array of pointers to each neuron of the input layer
    template <std::size_t LayerSize>
    auto makeLayerPtrs(std::array<InputNeuron, LayerSize> &inputLayer) {
        return makeLayerPtrs(inputLayer, std::make_index_sequence<LayerSize>{});
    }

    // Creates an array of pointers to each neuron of the given layer
    template <std::size_t LayerSize, std::size_t... LayerIdx>
    auto makeLayerPtrs(Layer<LayerSize> &layer, std::index_sequence<LayerIdx...>) {
        return std::array<NeuronBase *, LayerSize>{layer.GetNeurons()[LayerIdx].get()...};
    }

    // Creates an array of pointers to each neuron of the given layer
    template <std::size_t LayerSize>
    auto makeLayerPtrs(Layer<LayerSize> &layer) {
        return makeLayerPtrs(layer, std::make_index_sequence<LayerSize>{});
    }

    // Creates an array of pointers to each neuron of the given layer
    template <std::size_t LayerNumber>
    auto makeLayerPtrs() {
        if constexpr (LayerNumber == 0) {
            return makeLayerPtrs(m_inputLayer);
        } else {
            return makeLayerPtrs(std::get<LayerNumber - 1>(m_hiddenLayers));
        }
    }

    // Creates a Neuron with the given array of pointers to the previous layer
    template <auto Dummy, std::size_t LayerSize>
    auto makeNeuron(std::array<NeuronBase *, LayerSize> const &previousLayerPtrs) {
        return std::make_unique<Neuron<LayerSize>>(previousLayerPtrs);
    }

    // Creates one hidden layer
    template <std::size_t LayerNumber, std::size_t LayerSize, std::size_t... LayerIdx>
    auto makeHiddenLayer(std::index_sequence<LayerIdx...>) {
        // Implicit shift to 1-based indexing of hidden layers
        auto const previousLayerPtrs = makeLayerPtrs<LayerNumber>();
        return Layer<LayerSize>{{makeNeuron<LayerIdx>(previousLayerPtrs)...}};
    }

    // Creates all of the hidden layers
    template <std::size_t... HiddenLayersIdx>
    auto makeHiddenLayers(std::index_sequence<HiddenLayersIdx...>) {
        return std::tuple{
            makeHiddenLayer<HiddenLayersIdx, HiddenSizes>(
                std::make_index_sequence<HiddenSizes>{}
            )...
        };
    }

    // Creates all of the hidden layers
    auto makeHiddenLayers() {
        return makeHiddenLayers(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(HiddenSizes)>{});
    }

    // Creates the output layer
    template <std::size_t... LayerIdx>
    auto makeOutputLayer(std::index_sequence<LayerIdx...>) {
        auto const lastHiddenLayerPtrs = makeLayerPtrs<sizeof...(HiddenSizes)>();
        return Layer<NumOutputs>{{makeNeuron<LayerIdx>(lastHiddenLayerPtrs)...}};
    }

    // Creates the output layer
    auto makeOutputLayer() {
        return makeOutputLayer(std::make_index_sequence<NumOutputs>{});
    }

protected:
    // Caution : reordered members
    std::array<InputNeuron,NumInputs> m_inputLayer;
    std::tuple<Layer<HiddenSizes>...> m_hiddenLayers;
    Layer<NumOutputs> m_outputLayer;
};
```

I'm relying on the (unresearched) assumption that one can call `std::get` on a partially-constructed `std::tuple`. I hope I understood your question correctly and that each neuron *should* be connected to all of the neurons from the previous layer.

I have inserted `std::unique_ptr`s where it made sense to me (a `Layer` owns its `Neuron`s), but since there's no polymorphism at that point you could just store the `Neuron`s themselves and spare the dynamic allocations.

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eSHUN8Tc0sitMtgd)